# Create new project option not showing in TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm using TFS 2015 and trying to create a new Project in TFS. Unfortunately "Create Project" link is not shown on my TFS Admin Page:

[image]

I'm sure My account (kalliman) is a part of Windows Administrators group has all rights in TFS:

[image]

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a team project from the web portal as opposed to Visual Studio was added in TFS 2015 Update 2. You are probably running an earlier release of TFS 2015.

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using **TFS 2015 Update 2 or later** then you can create a team project from the web as well.  Otherwise you still have to do this in VS through Team Explorer.

About how to check the version info your TFS, please refer this tutorial: [What version of Team Foundation Server do I have?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2013/11/21/what-version-of-team-foundation-server-do-i-have/)

If your TFS is already 2015 update2 or later. Please double check your permission. If you're not a member of the **Project Collection Administrators Group**, [get added as one](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/add-administrator-tfs). To create team projects you must have the Create new projects permission set to Allow. And make sure if any other group including you have not set this permission to deny. In TFS, **deny trumps allow**.

Comment: This was the problem. Thanks :)